# JQGrid setRowData After inline edit

Tags: jqgrid

I'm having a problem updating a row after an inline edit.
My ColModel is:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', editable: true },
    { name: 'ReferenceEmail', index: 'ReferenceEmail', editable: true },
      // hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true}
    { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', editable: true, edittype: "select",
      editoptions: { value: "Mr:Mr;Mrs:Mrs;Ms:Ms;Doctor:Doctor;Sir:Sir"} },
    { name: 'Forename', index: 'Forename', editable: true },
    { name: 'Surname', index: 'Surname', editable: true },
    { name: 'Study_Manager', index: 'Study_Manager', editable: true,
      edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "True:True;False:False"} }
]
```

I plan to set the referenceemail col value = the new edited email value, so i have:

```
ondblClickRow: function (id, ri, ci) {
            lastSelUser = id;
            $("#UserGrid").editRow(id, true, false, reload);
        }
```

which in turn calls reload onsuccess of the edit,

```
function reload(result) {
    var cell = $("#UserGrid").getCell(lastSelUser, 'Email');
    var newEmail = $(cell).val();
    $("#UserGrid").saveRow(lastSelUser, false);

    $("#UserGrid").setRowData(lastSelUser, { ReferenceEmail: newEmail });


    var ref = $("#UserGrid").getCell(lastSelUser, 'ReferenceEmail');
    alert($(cell).val());
    alert($(ref).val());

}
```

Now my reference email doesnt get updated - the alert of the `cell value` returns correctly, but the alert of the `ref(referenceemail) value` is undefined and i've checked that the id is infact correct.

I've tried putting the `saverow` after the `setRowData`, but that makes no difference to the outcome.

Once again,
I greatly appreciate any and all insight into the problem.

Regards,
Byron Cobb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial solution has been found for anyone wondering. The jqGrid editRow accepts the following paramaters:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").editRow(rowid, keys, oneditfunc, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc,errorfunc, afterrestorefunc
```

.setRowData doesnt seem to work in the succesfunc, but it does work in aftersavefunc, so my new call is `$("#UserGrid").editRow(id, true, false, false, false, false, reload);` instead of `$("#UserGrid").editRow(id, true, false, reload);`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understood correctly your question.

It seems to me, that use should use `aftersavefunc` parameter of `editRow` instead of `succesfunc` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow). The event `aftersavefunc` will be called **after the data will be saved** in the jqGrid. The event `succesfunc` will be called only after `$.ajax` (no local data editing support) and immediately after the request completed **before the data are saved** in the grid.

The `aftersavefunc` event receive as parameters `rowid` - id of modified row, and `res` - response from the server. So if the `ReferenceEmail` field can be set by the server based on `Email` value you can use the results. To set `ReferenceEmail` field you can just use

```
$("#UserGrid").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'ReferenceEmail', data);
```

where `data` is the new value of `ReferenceEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

From the JQGrid documentation:

```
$("#updateButton").click( function(){
    var success=jQuery("#list5").jqGrid('setRowData',11,{amount:"333.00",tax:"33.00",total:"366.00",note:"<img src='images/user1.gif'/>"});

if(success) {
alert("Succes. Write custom code to update row in server"); 
}
   else {
       alert("Can not update");
}
```