# jQGrid reload grid after save inline button click

Tags: jqgrid

I was looking here to find out how to reload grid after save row:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

[JQGrid setRowData After inline edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227406/jqgrid-setrowdata-after-inline-edit)

[The afterInsertRow : function(ids) method is not executing when I use gridview:true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449317/the-afterinsertrow-functionids-method-is-not-executing-when-i-use-gridviewtr)

So i come up with this solution:

```
 onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    var tr;
                    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                        if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                            grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel); 

                            //this line doing the reload
                            grid.jqGrid('saveRow', id, true, '', '', '', '', reloadGrid());
                            tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(lastSel);

                            $("div.ui-inline-edit", tr).show();
                            $("div.ui-inline-save, div.ui-inline-cancel", tr).hide();
                        }
                        lastSel = id;
                    }

                },
```

I am using Actions formatter

```
     { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 60, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                                formatoptions: {
                                    keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                                    delOptions: myDelOptions,
                                    afterSave: hideDelIcon,
                                    afterRestore: hideDelIcon
                                }
                            }
```

Grid properties

```
rowNum: 10000,
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                height: "100%",
                editurl: '/Admin/Edit/',
                grouping: true,
                groupingView: {
                    groupField: ['race'],
                    groupColumnShow: [false],
                    groupText: ['<b class="selection-race">{0}</b>'],
                    groupDataSorted: true
                },
                ondblClickRow: function (id, ri, ci) {
                    var tr;
                    // edit the row and save it on press "enter" key
                    grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null);
                    tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(lastSel);
                    //$("div.ui-inline-edit, div.ui-inline-del", tr).hide();
                    $("div.ui-inline-edit", tr).hide();
                    $("div.ui-inline-save, div.ui-inline-cancel", tr).show();                    
                },
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    var tr;
                    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                        // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
                        // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
                        // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
                        // if jqGrid not in editing state
                        if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                            grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel); 

                            grid.jqGrid('saveRow', id, true, '', '', '', '', reloadGrid());
                            tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(lastSel);
                            //$("div.ui-inline-edit, div.ui-inline-del", tr).show();
                            $("div.ui-inline-edit", tr).show();
                            $("div.ui-inline-save, div.ui-inline-cancel", tr).hide();
                        }
                        lastSel = id;
                    }

                },
                loadComplete: function () {

                    $(this).find("div.ui-inline-del").hide();

                    var ids = jQuery("#Grid1").getDataIDs();

                    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                        var cl = ids[i];
                        $("tr#" + $.jgrid.jqID(cl)).prev().children().find("span.ui-icon-circlesmall-minus").hide();                        
                    }

                    var mids = jQuery("#Grid1").getDataIDs();

                    for (var i = 0; i < mids.length; i = i + 1) {
                        var cl2 = jQuery.jgrid.jqID(mids[i]);
                        var rowData = $("#Grid1").getRowData(cl2);

                        if (rowData.isonline == 'false') {
                            var trElement = jQuery("#" + cl2, jQuery('#sGrid1'));
                            trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content');
                            trElement.addClass('not-approved');
                        }
                    }

                    $(".rowCount").text($("#Grid1").getGridParam("reccount"))   
                },

                beforeRequest: function () {                    
                    $('#Grid1').setGridWidth(903, true);
                }
            }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#Pager1', { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, {}, myDelOptions, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false });
```

Predefined functions

```
var lastSel, rowdata,
                grid = $("#Grid1"),
                getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
                    var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i = 0, l = cm.length;
                    for (; i < l; i += 1) {
                        if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                            return i; // return the index
                        }
                    }
                    return -1;
                },
                myDelOptions = {
                    processing: false,
                    mtype: "POST", reloadAfterSubmit: true, //delData: { name: rowdata.name, isgood: rowdata.isgood }
                    serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                        //var rowdata = jQuery('#Grid1').getRowData(postdata.id);
                        // append postdata with any information 
                        return { id: postdata.id, uploadinfoid: postdata.uploadinfoid, oper: postdata.oper, name: rowdata.name, isfast: rowdata.isfast, isgood: rowdata.isgood, isdead: rowdata.isdead, isslow: rowdata.isslow, isheavy: rowdata.isheavy, isonline: rowdata.isonline };
                    },
                    // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes to the server
                    // so I use "processing:true" setting and delete the row manually in onclickSubmit
                    onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, rowid) {
                        rowdata = jQuery('#Grid1').getRowData(rowid);
                        // we can use onclickSubmit function as "onclick" on "Delete" button
                        // delete row
                        grid.delRowData(rowid);
                        $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();

                        if (grid[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
                            // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                            // TODO: deleting the last row from the last page which number is higher as 1
                            grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: grid[0].p.page}]);
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                },

                hideDelIcon = function (rowid) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("tr#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid) + " div.ui-inline-del").hide();
                    }, 50);
                },

                reloadGrid = function (rowid, result) {

                    $("#Grid1").trigger("reloadGrid");
                };
```

It is working but the problem is, grid getting reloaded every time after row clicked but not after save button clicked. It is not right behavior because there is no reason to process unreasonable server request and reload grid on each row click.

How may i change that behavior? I want to reload grid only on save button click.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that you should just include `$("#Grid1").trigger("reloadGrid");` or `$("#Grid1").trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);` in the `hideDelIcon` function:

```
hideDelIcon = function (rowid) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("tr#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid) + " div.ui-inline-del").hide();
        // the next line should be added
        $("#Grid1").trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: so i removed `grid.jqGrid('saveRow', id, true, '', '', '', '', reloadGrid());` from `onSelectRow` and added `$("#Grid1").trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);` to `hideDelIcon` and it is working. By the way what is the difference if i add additional param `[{current:true}]` to `trigger()`?

Comment: @Joper: Why you removed `reloadGrid()` from the `saveRow` parameters? You should have call of `reloadGrid` in all cases of `editRow` and `saveRow` call **and** in the `afterSave` event handler of actions formatter. The usage inside of `afterRestore` event handler seems me unneeded. You use `hideDelIcon` as both `afterSave` and `afterRestore`. About the parameters of `reloadGrid` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014)

Comment: Because when it is there it is reloading the gird in row click but i want grid to be reloaded just on save button click.